# Changing two factor authentication breaks heroku-api calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku

Using the [heroku-api gem][1], there are the following commands in a rake task

```
heroku = Heroku::API.new
resp = heroku.post_ps_restart(ENV['HEROKU_APP_NAME'])
```

Moving the google authenticator to a new Iphone reset the heroku two factor authentication, which meant that running the rake task triggered an exception:

Error Details – Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)

```
body: “{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}”
  [1]: https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the two factor authentication changes the auth:token. So find the new value by running

heroku auth:token

and use the new value for the api-key. If you have set the value in the `HEROKU_API_KEY` ENV variable on production then run

heroku config:set HEROKU_API_KEY = new_value_of_auth:token

However, note that setting the HEROKU_API_KEY on your local machine with interfere with the auth command from the heroku toolbelt (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication)).